# HTML ActionLink not sending to desired url in a new tab

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

Here is the code block:

```
<p>
                Confira abaixo as perguntas frequentes. Se ainda assim
                precisar, você poderá fazer @Html.ActionLink("contato nas unidades mais próximas", 
                "Index", "UnidadesEstados", new { target = "_blank" })
                ou por <a href="">e-mail</a>.
</p>
```

If I remove the `new { target = "_blank" }` the page open correctly in the same tab.
I want to open this in a new tab, but when I execute, the URL that open its like:

```
http://localhost:61467/FAQ?**Length=15**
```

What I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Hi and welcome on Stackoverflow. Please use the code formatting for clarity. I am adding it for you now.

Answer (score 0):

I had included a null parameter between the others and this did the trick:

@Html.ActionLink("contato nas unidades mais próximas", "Index", "UnidadesEstados", null, new { target = "_blank" })